# Simple form multiple select with simple array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Using this line of code:

```
<%= m.input :battery, :collection => ["1","2","3","4"], :input_html => { :multiple => true } %>
```

I see a perfectly rendered multi-select menu in my form.

However, **when I submit the form** (after selecting 1 and 2) I receive the following:

```
1.9.3p374 :012 > Style.find(402).battery
  Style Load (1.8ms)  SELECT `styles`.* FROM `styles` WHERE `styles`.`id` = 402 LIMIT 1
 => "---\n- ''\n- '1'\n- '2'\n"
```

Now when I reload the Style edit form, nothing is selected in the multi-select, and if I resubmit, my previous selections are **overwritten**:

```
=> "---\n- ''\n"
```

Obviously the format being used is not being interpretted correctly by the form

**Controller update action**

```
@style = Style.find(params[:id]) 
@style.update_attributes(params[:style])
```

**Params hash**

```
"battery"=>["", "1", "2"]
```

**UPDATE**

After adding `serialize :battery, Array` to my style model I am now seeing:

```
Style Load (0.1ms)  SELECT `styles`.* FROM `styles` WHERE `styles`.`id` = 402 LIMIT 1
 => ["", "1", "2"]
```

Most importantly, the form is loading the DB data now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save an array in your battery field u can use

```
serialize :battery, Array
```

in model